# How to limit actors per user

Tags: scala, akka

I am trying to understand how I could model this with akka.

My system processes messages for users, and the messages have to be processed serially for each user i.e. I cannot have 2+ actors processing a message at the same time for the same user.

So if I get 100 messages, and they are all for different users, I can spawn as many actors as I need to handle them.

But if I get 100 messages and they are for only 10 users, I have to ensure there is only 1 actor processing a given user at the same time.

How could I model this in Akka?  How could I filter messages or manage that only 1 actor per user?

note:  Each message will have a UserId with it.

Comment: Assuming userid is unique across the application, why not name the actor using userid? This way you could search for the actor and if its not present create one, and send the message to that particular actor.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information given, it sounds like you should consider using Cluster Sharding, and shard based on the user id.  There are other solutions too, but this is probably a good fit and very simple to add based on what you've described.

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to have a map between user id and its actor in your request accepting actor. As such, every actor has a mailbox, so that it will queue the incoming messages to a certain extent (it's up to you to set up the mailbox size, it can even be unlimited, as far as memory allows).

In other words,

```
class RequestAcceptor extends Actor {
  var users: Map[UserId, ActorRef] = Map.empty
  def receive = {
    case r@UserRequest(userId) => 
      val maybeActor = users.get(userId)
      if (maybeActor.isDefined) {
        maybeActor.get ! r
      } else {
        val actor = Props(classOf[ProcessingActor])
        users += userId -> actor
        actor ! r
      }
  }
}
```

Of course, you have to take care about the mailbox overflow in this case, but that would be a separate question, which is most probably should better be solved with Akka Streams.